# Every irreducible character of $S_n$ is an integer valued function.

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups, characters

Every irreducible character of $S_n$ is an integer valued function. Why is this true? I have seen this question posted before, but I did not understand the solution.

The only solution I can find deals with Galois theory which I am not very familiar with. I have also seen it suggested that the Specht modules over $\mathbb{C}$ give matrix representations with integer entries. I am not sure why this is true.

Comment: You don't give any idea of what your confusion is, so I expect that you are only going to get duplicate answers.  [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10635/why-are-the-characters-of-the-symmetric-group-integer-valued) for instance.

Comment: The Statement about Specht modules is worked out by GD James within the first 15 pages of his book on representations of symmetric groups: http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~webb/oldteaching/Year2010-11/the-representation-theory-of-the-symmetric-groups-SLN.pdf

Comment: @DavidHill Can you be more explicit? I didn't see this specific result in there.

Comment: I guess I had in mind results on page 16--Corollary 4.11 and Theorem 4.12. They are both based on the more general Theorem 4.9 on page 15, which is what I had in mind. I guess, technically, those results don't *quite* do it (though, if you look at the proofs hard enough I think the statement that the Specht modules are defined over $\mathbb{Z}$ is there). It is definitely proven in section 8. Anyway, you should really just read the manuscript.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2792741/11619).

Answer (score 1):

Personally I do not know how to do this without either Galois theory or the construction of the Specht modules. Here is the Galois theory argument, just to record it here. An element $g$ of a finite group $G$ is called [*rational*](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Rational_element) if $\chi(g)$ is rational (equivalently, integer) for every character $\chi$; $G$ itself is called [rational](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Rational_group) if every element of $G$ is rational.

> **Proposition:** $g$ is rational iff it is conjugate to $g^m$ for every $m$ coprime to the order of $g$.

*Proof.* Write $n$ for the order of $g$. If $\rho : G \to GL(V)$ is a representation of $G$ with character $\chi$, then $\rho(g) : V \to V$ is a matrix of order $n$ and hence its eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots \lambda_d$ are $n^{th}$ roots of unity. These live in the Galois extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ whose Galois group is the group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^{\times}$ of units $\bmod n$, where $m \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^{\times}$ acts by $\zeta_n \mapsto \zeta_n^m$. It follows that

$$\chi(g) = \sum_{i=1}^d \lambda_i$$

is rational iff it is fixed by every element of the Galois group. But the application of $\zeta_n \mapsto \zeta_n^m$ exactly gives us $\chi(g^m) = \sum_{i=1}^d \lambda_i^m$, so $\chi(g)$ is rational iff $\chi(g) = \chi(g^m)$ for every $m \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^{\times}$. Because characters separate conjugacy classes, this is true for every character iff $g$ and $g^m$ are conjugate. $\Box$

> **Claim:** The symmetric groups $S_n$ are rational.

*Proof.* If $\sigma \in S_n$ is a permutation with cycle lengths $\ell_1, \dots \ell_d$ (so order $\text{lcm}(\ell_1, \dots \ell_d)$, let $m$ be relatively prime to its order (equivalently, to each cycle length). Then $\sigma^m$ is a permutation with the same cycle lengths, so it is conjugate to $\sigma$. $\Box$

Answer (score 0):

I think the following can be a simple argument: one can prove that, for $G$ a finite group and $V$ a representation of $G$,
$$
\chi_{V^*}(g)=\overline{\chi_V}(g)=\chi_V\left(g^{-1}\right) \quad \forall g \in G,
$$
where $V^*$ denotes the dual space of $V$ and $\chi_V$ denotes the character of the representation $V$.
Now, let $\sigma \in S_n$. Its conjugacy class depends on its cycle structure:
$$ \sigma =
\underbrace{(\cdot) \cdots(\cdot)}_{m_1} \underbrace{(\cdot \cdot) \cdots(\cdot \cdot)}_{m_2} \cdots \underbrace{(\overbrace{\cdots \ \cdots \ \cdots}^{n \text { elements }}) \cdots(\cdots \ \cdots \ \cdots)}_{m_n}.
$$
Now notice that if $\sigma$ is a cycle,then $\sigma^{-1}$ is a cycle of the same lenght, using an abuse of notation: $(\cdots \ \cdots \ \cdots)^{-1} = (\cdots \ \cdots \ \cdots)$. If $\sigma$ is a product of disjoint cycles, then:
$$ 
\sigma^{-1} =
\underbrace{(\cdot)^{-1} \cdots (\cdot)^{-1}}_{m_1} \underbrace{(\cdot \cdot)^{-1} \cdots (\cdot \cdot)^{-1}}_{m_2} \cdots \underbrace{(\overbrace{\cdots \ \cdots \ \cdots}^{n \text { elements }})^{-1} \cdots (\cdots \ \cdots \ \cdots)^{-1}}_{m_n}
$$
(where we have used that disjoint cycles commute) has the same cycle structure of $\sigma$. So, $\sigma$ and $\sigma^{-1}$ are conjugates, and since the character $\chi_V$ is constant on conjugacy classes, $\chi_V(\sigma) = \chi_V(\sigma^{-1})$. Now, using the first formula:
$$ \overline{\chi_V(\sigma)} = \chi_V(\sigma^{-1}) = \chi_V(\sigma) \quad \forall \sigma \in S_n.$$

Comment: This proves that the characters are real-valued. I don't see how this implies they're integer-valued.

Comment: @LukasHeger right, I need to show it is rational. This suffices, because every character is also algebraic since $\sigma^n = 1$.

Comment: I think Lukas's point was that it is not sufficient for every element to be conjugate to its inverse. That is true also for example in the dihedral group $D_n$ of symmetries of a regular $n$-gon. Yet, the rotations in the dihedral group have as character values numbers like $2\cos(2\pi k/n)$ for all $k$. Those are not all rational (but they are real and algebraic).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yes, as I have already said, I missed the part where I prove the character is rational.